# Cause of assertion failure

Tags: groovy

Any idea what would cause this assertion failure in a Groovy script?

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: exception while dumping process stream
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ProcessGroovyMethods$ByteDumper.run(ProcessGroovyMethods.java:488)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Bad file descriptor
    at java.io.FileInputStream.available(Native Method)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:325)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:90)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ProcessGroovyMethods$ByteDumper.run(ProcessGroovyMethods.java:484)
    ... 1 more
```

I'm running Groovy 1.8.3 with JVM 1.6.0_14. I noticed an old bug report that was similar but I perform a waitFor() call after every process is started and it's reported to be fixed in 1.6.x.

I can't trap the exception apparently so I don't know exactly where it is happening. However, I'm guessing it occurs in this code segment:

```
  def pipedOutputStream = new PipedOutputStream()
  process.consumeProcessOutput(
    new TeeOutputStream(System.out, pipedOutputStream),
    new TeeOutputStream(System.err, pipedOutputStream))
  new PipedInputStream(pipedOutputStream).eachLine {
    (it =~ /condition/).find { process.destroy() }
  }

  System.exit(0)
```

Comment: Which `TeeOutputStream` are you using?  My guess would be that the condition is being met, so you are calling `process.destroy()` which is pulling the plug on one of the Streams.  Also, does it still fail if you use an up to date version of Groovy and an up to date version of Java 6?

Comment: Will continue discussion at https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-5406?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=296298#comment-296298